# Php PDO query security

Tags: php, security, pdo

I am new to the PDO class, I have been using MYSQLI since just now and I am kind of confused. This question is rather simple but I cannot find the answer in straight text anywhere in the manual. So calling `$pdo->query(some query)` will automatically escape the query and will not leave any room for potential injections of any kind. Is this true?

Comment: No. That's why you cannot find it in the manual

Comment: Well, how do I escape the query then? If I run prepare() and then query() it throws an error.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**NO, this is NOT true.**

To avoid any risk of `mysql injections` you will need either `prepared statments` or to escape properly your variables (which would involve you to manually escape each variable before submit). I would suggest to use prepared statements because they are way easier to use. Please read this post [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1). You can either have those with `mysqli` OR `PDO`, a nice example of PDO prepared statments, token from stackoverflow

```
$id  = 1;
$stm = $pdo->prepare("SELECT name FROM table WHERE id=?");
$stm->execute(array($id));
$name = $stm->fetchColumn();
```

You can learn [**more here**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info) about PDO prepared statements. I would also like you to have a look here **[How can prepared statements protect from SQL injection attacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263371/how-prepared-statements-can-protect-from-sql-injection-attacks/8265319#8265319)**

Comment: Well, you don't *need* prepared statements to avoid SQL injection; escaping properly is perfectly fine too.

Comment: @deceze you do. prepared statement makes formatting proper, complete and obligatory. while manual formatting doesn't

Comment: @Your You can avoid SQL injections *without* prepared statements. Nobody argues that prepared statements make it *easier*, but they're not the only solution! Don't spread unnecessary FUD.

Comment: @deceze you cannot. using prepared statement for the dynamic part of the every query in your application is the only way. Everything else is error prone.

Comment: @Your Yes, manually escaping is *error prone*, but **if done right** it prevents SQL injection just fine!

Answer (score 0):

the *query* function is not safe.

you better use *prepare* of the PDO object.

e.g.

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("select * from mytable where myattr = :attr");
```

the $sth handler can be used to set the placeholder in your query (e.g. **:attr** in this example)

you have two choice :

> either you use an array directly in the execute function of the handler :

```
$sth->execute (array ('attr', $myattr));
```

> or the *bindParam* function of the handler then *execute*

```
$sth->bindParam ('attr', $myattr);
$sth->execute();
```

The method provide a good way of escaping the single quotes in your arguments.

**note** : also take a loot at [Why you Should be using PHP’s PDO for Database Access (net.tutsplus.com)](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/)

Answer (score -1):

No, `PDO::query` is just as vulnerable as `mysql_query` or any other raw query method.

If you do

```
$sql = "SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE baz = '$var'";
```

and `$var` is

```
Robert'; DROP TABLE users; --
```

so the result is

```
SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE baz = 'Robert'; DROP TABLE users; --'
```

then *no* API can help you, because no API can tell the difference between what the *query part* and what the *user value* is. This difference is only clear to the API when you use *prepared statements* or *escape special characters in the value properly*.

Read [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/).